# Decomposing Test Functions

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Show that every test function $\varphi$ $\in$ $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ can be written as $\varphi(x) = x \psi(x) + c\varphi_0(x)$ where $\varphi_0(x)$ is a fixed test function (with $\varphi_0(0) \neq 0)$, $\psi$ $\in$ $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, and $c$ is a constant.

I'm not really sure where to begin on this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean $\varphi(x) = x\psi(x) +c\varphi_0(x)$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\vp}{\varphi}$
Your $\vp$s and $\psi$s are all over the place alas. I will assume
you want to write $\psi$ as $x\vp+c\vp_0$.

Putting $x=0$ we need $\psi(0)=c\vp(0)$, so we need $c=\psi(0)/\vp_0(0)$.
Then we must have
$$\vp(x)=\frac{\psi(x)-c\vp_0(x)}{x}.$$
So we need to check this is $C^\infty$ at $0$ (when we assign a suitable
value to $\vp(0)$) as it is clearly compactly supported.

Comment: What's $ \phi_0$ here? How did you define it?

Comment: @Ashkan It is an arbitrary test function such that $\varphi_0(0) \ne 0$

Comment: I think I just need L'Hopital's Rule to finish this off.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
f(x):= \varphi(x)-\frac{\varphi(0)}{\varphi_0(0)}\varphi_0(x)=\varphi-\alpha\varphi_0
\end{align}
equals $0$ when $x=0$, i.e. $f(0) = 0$. Next, observe
\begin{align}
f(x) = \int^x_0f'(s)\ ds = xf'(x)-\int^x_0sf''(s)\ ds = x\left(f'(x)-\frac{1}{x}\int^x_0 sf''(s)\ ds \right).
\end{align}
(Note that I used the fact $f(0) =0$.) Hence it suffices to show that
\begin{align}
G(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}\int^x_0 sf''(s)\ ds & \text{ if } x \neq 0\\
0 & \text{ if } x = 0
\end{cases} 
\end{align}
is in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$.

More hint: for $x \neq 0$, we that
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{G(x+h)-G(x)}{h} =\ f''(x) -\frac{1}{x^2}\int^x_0sf''(s)\ ds= \frac{1}{2}f''(x)+\frac{1}{2x^2}\int^x_0 s^2f'''(s)\ ds
\end{align}

Comment: $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^K \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k + \mathcal{O}(x^{K+1})$ really means that $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^{k-1} + \mathcal{O}(x^{K})$ is $C^{K-1}$ at $x=
0$

Comment: @user1952009 I'm trying to avoid using Lagrange remainder since the remainder will depend on some unknown function $\xi(x)$.